# Retrieving data fails 80% times from GAE datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

This is the method i am using to save data in GAE datastore. data is saving but at the return statement of this method i am retrieving the saved object and returning it, it is returning null, help me to resolve this problem.

```
 public UserInfo saveEmergencyUserInfo(UserInfo userInfo) {
    Key userInfoKey = ofy().save().entity(userInfo).now();
    return ofy().load().type(userInfo.class).filterKey(userInfo).first().now();
 }
```

Comment: Why do you want to read an object that you already have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal if you read [Datastore writes and data visibility](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/#Java_Datastore_writes_and_data_visibility).  Design your application in such as way that it can tolerate a delay after writing before reading is necessary.  One way is to cache recently written data with [Memcache](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache).  Such a design approach is sometimes called [Command & Query Responsibility Segregation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554200.aspx), and is useful to decouple subsystems and improve application scalability.

Answer (score 1):

You're encountering "Eventual Consistency". For a good explanation, plus a path forward if you need to be able to immediately query for freshly-written data, see [Balancing Strong and Eventual Consistency](https://cloud.google.com/developers/articles/balancing-strong-and-eventual-consistency-with-google-cloud-datastore) for a general discussion, and [Structuring Data for Strong Consistency](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency) for Java SDK-specifics.